# Prometheus not monitoring all EC2 instances of a region

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, system-monitoring

I have set up Prometheus for the monitoring of my AWS EC2 instances, but the issue is taht Prometheus is showing up only 1 instance, however in my AWS instance account there are 2 instances running. Both instances are running in the same region, but I don't know why it is showing only 1 instance.

Here is the my configuration in `prometheus.yml`:

```
job_name: 'AWS-Instance' scrape_interval: 5s ec2_sd_configs: - region: us-east-2 access_key: ************ secret_key: ************ port: 9100 relabel_configs: - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_public_ip] regex: '(.*)' target_label: address replacement: '${1}:9100' - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Name] target_label: instance
```